# Drupal - adding a shortcut link that bypasses the overlay

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Is it possible to add a shortcut to the menu bar that when clicked, goes straight to the link provided.

e.g. currently if I'm on `http://mywebsite.com` and I click a shortcut to the admin menu, the url changes to `http://mywebsite.com/#overlay=admin` and it appears in the popup overlay.

What I want is to go directly to the admin url without the overlay (`http://mywebsite.com/admin`). It's slow and clunky and can't stand it. However on some occasions it is useful to have it in a popup so it doesn't navigate away from the current page.

I know there's a setting to force all overlay actions to go straight to the page, but I don't want that. I only want a single shortcut link to bypass the overlay, so I can use the admin area directly when I need to, and everything else stays as is.

Can this be done for a single shortcut, or can it only be set one way for everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal won't open the overlay if you can get the class 'overlay-exclude' onto the link.

You should be able to get that class onto the link by overriding [theme_menu_link()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/theme_menu_link/7) in your theme and checking whether the link belongs to the shortcut set as you go.

You also may be able to use javascript to accomplish the same thing, say something like `jQuery('.toolbar-shortcuts a[href="/admin"]').addClass('overlay-exclude')`

Comment: Just did a quick in browser test with jQuery and that did indeed work. Cheers :)